# Splash Screen not displaying in iPad but displaying on simulator

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, ipad, png

In my iPad app which is restricted to **UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight** , i added splash image by named **default-Landscape.png & default-Landscape@2x.png** images but it is rendering in simulator but not in my iPad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All file names are case-sensitive.

rename them to : Default-Landscape.png & Default-Landscape@2x.png

with capital "D"

in simulator it isnt case-sensitive but in device it is

hope it helps. happy coding :)

Comment: The default setting for the Mac OS X HFS+ file system is case-insensitive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you mean the Default image.

Go to the Target - Summery view and check the the image is set for "Launch Images" and that there is no error or warning (usually due to size issue, you will see a small yellow mark over the picture)

- deleted the app from both device and simulator
- Clean your product
- and reinstall on device via xcode.

Assuming you still have a problem, try to open the original image in Photoshop and re-export it as PNG 24

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Automatic orientation support for iPhone and iPad apps By Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1588/_index.html)

**iPad-only applications:**

Create a launch image for each supported orientation in the PNG format. Each launch image must be 1024 x 748 pixels (for landscape) or 768 x 1004 pixels (for portrait).

Default launch image files:

```
Default-PortraitUpsideDown.png - upside-down portrait version.

Default-LandscapeLeft.png - left-oriented landscape version.

Default-LandscapeRight.png - right-oriented landscape version.

Default-Portrait.png - generic portrait version.

Default-Landscape.png - generic landscape version.

Default.png - default portrait launch. Its usage is strongly discouraged, use more specific launch images instead.For iPad launch images, do not include the status bar region.
```

Create launch images of these sizes:

```
For portrait:

    768 x 1004 pixels

    1536 x 2008 pixels (high resolution)

For landscape:

    1024 x 748 pixels

    2048 x 1496 pixels (high resolution)
```

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me with an Ionic 3 app.  Eventually I discovered the image it was loading is `Default@2x~universal~anyany.png`